# HTML5 Validation in Visual Studio 2010 - script still requires type tag?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html

I am validating against HTML5 obtained through VS2010 SP1. I was under the impression that this simplification was possible:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js">...</script>
```

to

```
<script src="foo.js">...</script>
```

In attempting this, I found:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <script src="../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
</head>
```

yielded this:

> Warning 1 Validation (HTML5): Element 'script' is missing required attribute 'type'.

Am I missing something? Is the Visual Studio XHTML5 validation more strict than the HTML5 doc necessitates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like it's been submitted to [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/667305/html5-editor-validator-fails-on-script-when-no-type-attribute-is-provided). The VS validator is being stricter than the `HTML5` spec.

Comment: I feel we should find a ruder word than 'stricter' for enforcement of wrong rules, in any walk of life...

Answer (score 24):

I resolved the issue by manually editing the schema file.

```
 <xsd:element name="script">
    ...
    <xsd:attribute name="type" vs:readonly="true" use="required">
    ...
```

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio 2010
2. Open a text editor as a user with administrative rights
3. Open the file `html_5.xsd` in the VS schemas folder
   `<Program Files>\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\schemas\html`
4. On line 617 (within the `xsd:element name="script"` tag) remove the `use="required"` attribute.
5. Save the file.
6. Reopen Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 3):

The file is in the \Program Files(x86)\ directory on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a better solution. I installed official plugin for Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 from MSDN named `HTML 5 Intellisense for Visual Studio 2010 and 2008`. It's for coding with HTML5.

You can view the details and download here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d771cbc8-d60a-40b0-a1d8-f19fc393127d

After installing, your validator should have a new option, choose HTML5, and VS will produce warnings no more.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed the HTML 5 Intellisense plugin, but I still had to edit the html5.xsd file to make it go away.